# How to Lattice deform for multiple objects?

Tags: modifiers, lattice

I'm trying to deform multiple objects all together by Lattice(Blender 3.2.0).
They were created by Array Modifier is not applied yet.
However I want to deform them diagonally compressed top like on top picture pink line but they just moved like on middle picture.
Next I tried to apply all object Lattice Deform but after applying rest of 4 has disappeared.

How can I deform array objects all together as a single object?

In case I uploaded blend file here.
https://ufile.io/o05y99se

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join all the objects (plane, cube, sphere) with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> instead of parenting them to the plane. Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to unparent the cube and sphere before joining them. Here's the result https://blend-exchange.com/b/9m2zyMqx

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! You solved my issue!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad i was able to help :)